kubectl get pods -n ${params.environment} -o wide > pod_list_deployment_name.txt
I wrote this command in a jenkins file:
kubectl get pods -n ${params.environment} -o wide > pod_list_deployment_name.txt 

I wrote a shell command in jenkins file I am repeatedly getting this error:
/home/jenkins/workspace/intern/INTERN_POD_DEBUG@tmp/durable-c42d2fc7/script.sh.copy: 33: Syntax

How do I prevent substitution in the above command?

Please [edit] your question and provide a [MRE] - without your Jenkinsfile code we cannot help you.

I think I understand what you are asking, but without a full error message we're all guessing here.  But, if you are trying to prevent a GString substitution with the syntax ${params.environment} you can do this:
sh "kubectl get pods -n \${params.environment} -o wide > pod_list_deployment_name.txt".

However, if you are trying to substitute the params.environment from Groovy into the command do this:
sh "kubectl get pods -n ${params.environment} -o wide > pod_list_deployment_name.txt"

